# How to retrieve induction loop information in custom environment?

Tags: sumo, flow-project

Hell guys,

I am trying to set up my own environment to train traffic lights to optimize the traffic flow. To do this I want to use area lane detectors. 
In the flow tutorials and examples usually general information is retrieved from the whole network, all vehicles on the network or traffic lights. These are provided by the Kernel base class.

For example information of traffic lights are retreived from the kernel api like this:

```
ids = kernel_api.trafficlight.getIDList()
```

and I would like to do such things:

```
ids = kernel_api.inductionloop.getIDList()
```

To get my desired information from the lane area detectors, no such option can be found in the kernel, nor anywhere else as far as I can say.
But as this is such a fundamental way of retrieving information from the simulation, I assume I missed something here or do I need to create my own Kernel?

It would be great, if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create your own Kernel code for matching your needs.